# How can i make an "uptime" command for my discord bot? (PYTHON)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Im making a discord bot in Python and i want to add a "g/stats"/"g/uptime", that when used the bot send how much time its been on. Ex: User: g/uptime  Bot: This bot has been on for 01 hours 23 minutes and 58 seconds.
How can i do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: On launch store the current time. When command is run grab the new time. Subtract the first from the second time. Voila!

Comment: You have to save the start timestamp on start event and than on this command, get current timestamp and return the difference

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems you want a timer in your program. The comments above also tell a way to use the start event and current timestamps. However, the way we could code a timer to keep track of the entire lifecycle of the program would be to:

1. Import Time. In order to use real time in python, you must use the time module.

```py
#import the time module
import time
```

2. Create a function that will execute the task. Create a timer that will run until the end of the program, format it to h/m/s and print when finished.

```py
def uptime(t = 1):
    while t:
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timer)
        time.sleep(1)
        t += 1
```

The above function will print out every second the program is running. You can tweak it so it only prints at the end of the programs lifecycle